# VBA & HTMLBody - Spacing between Body and Signature

Tags: html, excel, vba

I will be using excel to send emails to my clients requesting certain files from them. I have everything working except for 1 small detail and I do not want to use this until I have that 1 detail figured out.

My email populates almost perfectly, except for the fact that at the end, there is about 3 lines of space between "Regards" and my signature. I'm not sure why this is happening. It shows up like this:

> Thank you for your attention in this matter.
>
> Regards,
>   
>   
>   
>   
>   Signature

Does anyone know how to fix it. My code is listed below:

```
Sub KYC_FATCA()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim signature As String

Dim AccOpen As String
Dim ConDoc As String
Dim SIP As String
Dim AFS As String
Dim W8 As String
Dim LEI As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup
For Each cell In Columns("G").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'KYC Account Opening Form
    If (Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value) = "No" Then
        AccOpen = "<b>KYC Account Opening Form</b> ." & "<br>" & "<br>"
    Else
        AccOpen = ""
    End If

    'Constating Document
    If (Cells(cell.Row, "J").Value) = "No" Then
        ConDoc = "<b>Constating Document</b> - ." & "<br>" & "<br>"
    Else
        ConDoc = ""
    End If

    'Statement of Policy and Guidelines (SIP&G)
    If (Cells(cell.Row, "L").Value) = "No" Then
        SIP = "<b>Statement of Policy and Guidelines (SIP&G)</b> - " & "<br>" & "<br>"
    Else
        SIP = ""
    End If

    'Audited Financial Statements (AFS)
    If (Cells(cell.Row, "M").Value) = "No" Then
        AFS = "<b>Audited Financial Statements (AFS)</b> - ." & "<br>" & "<br>"
    Else
        AFS = ""
    End If

    'W-8BEN-E Form
    If (Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value) = "No" Then
        W8 = "<b>W-8BEN-E Form</b> - " & "<br>" & "<br>"
    Else
        W8 = ""
    End If

    'Legal Entity Identifier (LEI)
    If (Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value) = "Needed" Then
        LEI = "<b>Legal Entity Identifier (LEI)</b> - " & "<br>" & "<br>"
    Else
        LEI = ""
    End If


    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       (Cells(cell.Row, "H").Value) = "yes" Then

        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
        .Display
        End With
        signature = OutMail.HTMLbody

        On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Text 'Whatever is in cell G
            .cc = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value

            'Testing if statements - The below one works perfect
            'If LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "Z").Value) = "" Then
            '    .cc = Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value
            'End If

            .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value & " - " & "Documentation Request" _

            .HTMLbody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>" & "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & ",<br>" & "<br>" & _
            "On behalf of " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & ", please by " & "<b><u>" & Cells(cell.Row, "Q").Text & "</b></u>" & "." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
            AccOpen & _
            ConDoc & _
            SIP & _
            AFS & _
            W8 & _
            LEI & _
            "If you have any questions and/or concerns, please contract your Relationship Manager, " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & "." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
            "Thank you for your attention in this matter." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
            "Regards," & "</p>" & _
            signature _

            'You can add files also like this
            If (Cells(cell.Row, "I").Value) = "No" Then
            .Attachments.Add ("C:doc")
            End If
            .Display  'This will open the message itself. If you'd like to send right away, use .Send

        End With

        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing

    End If

Next cell

cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
signature = OutMail.HTMLbody
```

This is a clever way to get the signature, but the default email body has a couple blank lines above the signature, and those are getting included when you concatenate the email.

I would visually check `signature` in a debugger and see what is in there, and [remove the stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txha70f6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you don't want.  A simple example might be:

```
Function RemoveBlankStuff(ByVal text as string) as string
    text = text.Replace("<P></P>","") 'Remove any empty paragraphs
    text = text.Replace("<BR>","")    'Remove any line breaks
    Return text;
End Function

signature = RemoveBlankStuff(OutMail.HTMLBody);
```

You will need to modify the above function depending on what you find in `signature`.

Comment: Hi John, I had a feeling that was causing the problem. Thanks for confirming it. I reviewed my signature in outlook and it doesn't have any blank lines or empty paragraphs at the beginning. Is there another place I can review the actual code that's being used to pull in the signature?

Comment: I am not sure it matters where it is coming from.  It's not like you can change it.  I would just write a simple function that takes the HTMLBody as input and returns a string with the stuff you don't want removed.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not quite following. I have to admit, this is the only thing I've ever done in VBA so my coding is very very limited. 

I inputted the code you wrote in place of my signature=OutMail.Htmlbody but I keep getting multiple errors. I'm sure you meant for me to do something else, however I do not know how to :( 

I appreciate the help though!

Comment: Edited to be a little more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar and running into the same issue.

This should work if you replace this portion of code:

```
        With OutMail
        .Display
        End With
        signature = OutMail.HTMLbody
```

With the following code - it effectively opens, deletes whitespace, and deletes/discards the e-mail created to get the signature:

```
  'gets default signature from e-mail
    With OutMail
        '2 = HTMLBody
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .Display
        'deletes blank space present before signature
        signature = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, "<p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>", "")
        'removes entire e-mail contents and then closes with discard
        OutMail.HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, OutMail.HTMLBody, "")
        OutMail.Close 1
    End With
```

Not sure if it makes a difference, but in .HTMLBody, I also start as -

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "Good Afternoon," & "<br>" & "whateveryourtextis" & "Thanks," & "<br><br>" & signature
```